# how to hide button from condition inside external function in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can we control the button hide by condition
for example, we have

```
<div class="button">
<button style="font-weight:bold" 
onclick="displayValue();"> Submit </button>
</div>
```

and we have javascript file with function displayValue()

```
function displayValue(arr){
    if(condition){
        //wanna hide the button if this condition is satisfied 
    }else{
        alert("in this condition, the button will still be showed")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply set `display` to `none`:

```js
function displayValue() {
  if (true) {
    document.querySelector("button").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <button style="font-weight:bold" onclick="displayValue();"> Submit </button>
</div>
```

If you use the function on multiple elements you could pass the element to the function too:

```js
function displayValue(element) {
  if (true) {
    element.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <button style="font-weight:bold" onclick="displayValue(this);"> Submit </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. btw, how can we change the button size in CSS. when I use width and height to control the button size in CSS, the button will not be located to the web centre(even I used text-align:center). Is this because the button is placed in div table?

Answer (score 1):

simple check its is true or not like

Javascript

```
function displayValue(arr) {
  if (true) {
    arr.style.display = "none"; //button will hide
  }else{
    alert("in this condition, the button will still be showed")
  }
}
```

And HTML like this

```
<div class="button">
  <button style="font-weight:bold" onclick="displayValue(this);"> Submit </button>
</div>
```